# как сделать что бы по клику на маркер яндекс карты в блоке менялся текст?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы по клику на маркер города в форме менялся заголовок на название города и менялся текст который под заголовком, вообще возможно ли такое реализовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовать, конечно, можно. У placemark (geoobject) есть поле events, куда можно вешать обработчик и вызывать нужный вам callback по клику.

```
placemark.events.add('click', onChangeMyTitle)
```

Демо можно посмотреть здесь https://jsfiddle.net/sck8dg16/13/

Суть простая:

1. Устанавливаем геообъекту properties с нужными нам данными, в данном
   случаи это city
2. Добавляем обработчик на onClick
3. По клику, достаём из событие нужное нам поле city
4. Показываем его в нужном нам месте